# Font from File in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: html, css

I've been trying at this for days, and I cannot figure it out.

I made an ASP.NET Web Forms project in VS and it shows this code for loading the font:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons-halflingsregular') format('svg');
}
```

I have this in my code:

```css
@font-face
{
 font-family: 'Raleway';
 src: url('fonts/Raleway-Regular.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
 src: url('fonts/Raleway-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
      url('fonts/Raleway-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Apparently this fixes IE11 (source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face ) */
   url('fonts/Raleway-Regular.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
   url('fonts/Raleway-Regular.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
   url('fonts/Raleway-Regular.svg#iosfix') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

It doesn't work. Any fixes/ideas/thoughts?

- A frustrated and confused student that needs a website submitted for an assessment soon

Comment: Your code looks fine, so questions are: 1. Is actual url is correct? Take a look at dev.tools on "Network" tab and check if font is actually being loaded. 2. Do you actually use this font in stylesheet? Provide example from your stylesheet that uses this font definition. 3. Is font looks fine in other browsers?

Comment: Works in Google Chrome, URLs are correct.

Comment: Switch to "Inspector" tab, select element with this font, Switch to "Computed style" tab at the right side and review `font-family` property value. Is it correct? Also try to replace definition of your own font with loading [same font](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Raleway) from Google Fonts, will it work?

Comment: It is using the correct name. If it helps the CSS where it's loaded is an external file.

Comment: If resulted CSS url is constructed correctly (and it is since it works in Chrome) - then it doesn't matter. The only remaining difference is font formats, used by Chrome and IE. I would propose to take a look what font format is loaded by IE (in "Network" tab) then comment our remove all references to font format except this one and check once again in Chrome and IE. If Chrome will stop displaying font (don't forget to clear / disable cache!) - then problem is in font file itself. Also try to use Google Fonts as I wrote above.